# Java, Sending data to different IPs

Tags: java, networking

I am making a simple chat client for fun, I have the Server/Client working and sending data perfectly. I would like to know how I can send data to selected users. The selecting part I can work out, but I don't know how to send things to the selected IPs. Here is my server so far.

```
package Server;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

/**
 * @class Connect
 * @date Feb 25, 2013 10:14:00 PM
 * @author Zach
 */

public class Connect { //Server
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(43595);

        while (server.isBound()) {

            Socket s = server.accept();
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());

            int length = in.read();
            byte[] data = new byte[length];
            in.read(data);
            String str = new String(data, "UTF-8");

            s.close();
        }
    }
}
```

I want to redirect information off of the server to a specific client

Answer (score 1):

Make an array of accepted sockets, in your case from "s" Socket, then you can loop it to find which client to send data to.

Comment: Yes, you can, after receiving data, just loop the array and send it to all connected clients (using the array that i told you)

Comment: Probably a `List`, or a `Map`, would be a better option, as the array assumes a fixed size.

Answer (score 0):

Make a class that handles each client:

```
public class ClientHandler {

Socket connection;
DataInputStream in;
DataOutputStream out;

public ClientHandler(Socket s) {
    connection = s;
}
public void startup() throws IOException {
    in = new DataInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
    out = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
    out.flush();
}

public void sendMessage(byte[] message) throws IOException {
    out.write(message);
}

}
```

Put a List in your server and assign an ID to each ClientHandler, then you can loop through your List and if the ID matches, use sendMessage() on the client.

I recommend you to use buffers for the input and output as they are more efficient.
I also recommend you to use threads in your server class, especially if handling multiple clients.

Comment: It is good practice to open `OutputStream`s first, when using sockets.